# Why Shake dependencies are explicitly `needed`?

Tags: shake-build-system

I find first [example](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.13.4/docs/Development-Shake.html) of `Shake` usage demonstrating a pattern that seems error prone:

```
    contents <- readFileLines $ out -<.> "txt"
    need contents
    cmd "tar -cf" [out] contents
```

Why do we need `need contents` when `readFileLines` reads them and `cmd` references them? Is this so we can avoid requiring `ApplicativeDo`?

Comment: I've tried to elaborate in an answer, but I'm not sure I've really got to the heart of the question. What do you see as the potential error? How do you think `ApplicativeDo` might help?

Comment: @Neil, thanks for being open minded :) So here's my view. From someone not experienced in Haskell, any seemingly "unnecessary" code raises questions like "Why do you recommend writing it this way"? Is this solving a lazy IO problem? Is this how you adapt parallel tasks to a `Monad` interface (compared with `Haxl` use of `ApplicativeDo`)? Why not define `tar` goal with proper semantics on input files instead? I may be overly cautious about complex Haskell stuff underneath `Shake` though.

Comment: so are you asking why the `need` is necessary? It's necessary because you have to tell Shake what `tar` will use, because it has no idea what `tar` does. You are right, people could define `tar inp out = do need inp; cmd "tar -cf" [out] inp` - and indeed in a larger build system I would encourage that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part of the confusion may be the types/semantics of `contents`. The file `out -<.> "txt"` contains a list of filenames, so `contents` is a list of filenames. When we `need contents` we are requiring the files themselves be created and depended upon, using the filenames to specify which files. When we pass `contents` on to `cmd` we are passing the filenames which `tar` will use to query the files.

So the key point is that `readFileLines` doesn't read the files in question, it only reads the filenames out of another file. We have to use `need` to make sure that using the files is fine, and then we actually use the files in `cmd`. Another way of looking at the three lines is:

1. Which files do we want to operate on?
2. Make sure those files are ready.
3. Use those files.

Does that make sense? There's no relationship with `ApplicativeDo` - it's presence wouldn't help us at all.